# How to create a view on GA to "include only" 1 specific IP

Tags: google-analytics

I have create a filter "include only" with my IP address and testing on real time overview seems to be picking other users as well (not only me).

I have also tried to exclude all traffic but with a regular expression

```
^(?!xx\.xx\.91\.88).*$
```

and some variants of this but this did not seem to work

I have again tested using the real time overview and does not seem to work

or should I be actually waiting for 24 hours to actually see this filter working ?
any workaround ?

Comment: Maybe a painful workaround.... create a new GA property and only include it in the code for the IP you want.

Comment: I cannot find the documentation for this atm, however real time reporting can take up to 2hrs to sync with changes. Also just create a test view, apply it and check the test view in 12-24hrs